# Why do I get connected to TOR nodes that I excluded in TORRC?

Tags: security, privacy, tor, rules, nodes

I'm testing the TOR browser bundle and I keep getting connected to exit nodes in countries that I've explicitly excluded in my `torrc`:

```
StrictNodes 1

ExcludeExitNodes {ad},{ar},{au},{at},{bs},{by},{be},{br},{io},{vg},{bg},{ca},{ky},{cl},{hr},{cy},{cz},{dk},{ee},{fk},{fi},{fr},{fx},{gf},{pf},{tf},{ge},{de},{gi},{gr},{gl},{gu},{hu},{is},{in},{ie},{im},{il},{it},{jp},{lv},{li},{lt},{lu},{mt},{mh},{mx},{mc},{an},{nl},{nz},{nf},{no},{pa},{pl},{pt},{re},{ro},{ru},{sa},{uk},{rs},{sg},{su},{es},{sh},{kn},{lc},{pm},{vc},{sj},{se},{ch},{tr},{ua},{gb},{us},{um},{va},{vi},{??}

ExcludeNodes {ad},{ar},{au},{at},{bs},{by},{be},{br},{io},{vg},{bg},{ca},{ky},{cl},{hr},{cy},{cz},{dk},{ee},{fk},{fi},{fr},{fx},{gf},{pf},{tf},{ge},{de},{gi},{gr},{gl},{gu},{hu},{is},{in},{ie},{im},{il},{it},{jp},{lv},{li},{lt},{lu},{mt},{mh},{mx},{mc},{an},{nl},{nz},{nf},{no},{pa},{pl},{pt},{re},{ro},{ru},{sa},{uk},{rs},{sg},{su},{es},{sh},{kn},{lc},{pm},{vc},{sj},{se},{ch},{tr},{ua},{gb},{us},{um},{va},{vi},{??}
```

In at least 1/3 of all cases, my exit nodes are from the Netherlands, Italy or Russia. How are the `torrc` settings overruled and is there any way to enforce them?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, one never get's any useful answers regarding TOR from EU/CANZUK member state websites, including Stack Exchange.

A I right that one cannot trust any security product coming from people in those regions? I'm being reminded about Crypto AG (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypto_AG) and 1G/2G/3G architecture (https://jstor.org/stable/pdf/26487508.pdf).

Has the time finally come where we should start looking into alternative products e.g. from Asia or the Global South?